# How to trigger code anytime a UItextfield is empty

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield

I would like to have code for anytime a UItextfield is empty. Not just on the `viewdidload` but all the time. I tried putting something like `if textField.isEmpty == true` in the editing changed action although the issue I was having is if you type more than 5 characters and then hold down backspace the code doesn't get triggered. Any ideas for what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need to subscribe on editing changed 
**How to check if the field is empty?**
let textField = UITextField()
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanged), for: .editingChanged)

```
@objc func textChanged () {
    if textField.text == "" || textField.text == nil {
        print("IS EMPTY")
    } else {
        print("NON EMPTY")
    }
}
```

**How to set max length to UITextField**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.delegate = self
    }
        
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard let textFieldText = textField.text,
            let rangeOfTextToReplace = Range(range, in: textFieldText) else {
                return false
        }
        let substringToReplace = textFieldText[rangeOfTextToReplace]
        let count = textFieldText.count - substringToReplace.count + string.count
        return count <= 5
    }
    
}
```

Comment: If you look at my question I explained that I tried that but when you hold down backspace after 5 characters the code doesn't get triggered

Comment: Let me clarify. You need to prevent putting more than 5 characters, right?

Comment: I updated code and add max length functionality way